# How to update with two condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am practicing mongodb.

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { item: "canvas", qty: 100, size: { h: 28, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "mat", qty: 85, size: { h: 27.9, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "mousepad", qty: 25, size: { h: 19, w: 22.85, uom: "cm" }, status: "P" },
   { item: "notebook", qty: 50, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "P" },
   { item: "paper", qty: 100, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "D" },
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, status: "D" },
   { item: "postcard", qty: 45, size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "sketchbook", qty: 80, size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "sketch pad", qty: 95, size: { h: 22.85, w: 30.5, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" }
] );
```

I tend to separate "cm" and "in", and update them, but it doesn't work

```
db.inventory.updateMany(
    { $or [ { "size.h": { $gt:8.75 }, "size.uom": "in" }, 
            {"size.h": { $gt:22.225 }, "size.uom": "cm"} ] },
    {
     $set: {status: "B"},
     $currentDate: {lastModified: true}
    }
)

2019-04-12T22:16:00.575-0700 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):2:6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing that is correct but you have a syntax error, you're missing colon after `$or`:

```
db.inventory.updateMany(
    { $or: [ { "size.h": { $gt:8.75 }, "size.uom": "in" }, 
            {"size.h": { $gt:22.225 }, "size.uom": "cm"} ] },
    {
    $set: {status: "B"},
    $currentDate: {lastModified: true}
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I don't notice I missed ' : '